How can I render a Razor Page (PageModel) to HTML?
As weird as may sound, is it possible to render a Razor Page (a PageModel derived class) to Html?
To give you an idea of why I'd need this, I'm looking for ways to try nest Razor Pages.
For example, if I have a ParentModel : PageModel and a ChildModel: PageModel, I'd like to be able to put Child.cshtml somehow in the Parent.cshtml.
EDIT: I'm fully aware of both partial views and ViewComponents. I don't like these solutions because I cannot use a Razor Page anymore. If that child view has some POST actions, I'm forced to put those actions in the parent ParentModel (or somewhere else) which I don't like.

In your case that you have a ParentModel : PageModel and a ChildModel: PageModel,  it is not possible to render a Razor Page (a PageModel derived class).
But there's another way to put Child.cshtml in the Parent.cshtml, you can use PartialView to implement nested pages.

A partial view is a .cshtml markup file without an @page directive
maintained within the Pages folder.

For example, you can try the following code
@await Html.PartialAsync("Child");

Or if you want to access a model:
@await Html.PartialAsync("Child", model);

For detailed information, you can refer to this article.

Thank you. I'm fully aware of both partial views and ViewComponents. I don't like these solutions because I cannot use a Razor Page anymore. If that child view has some POST actions, I'm forced to put those actions in the parent ParentModel (or somewhere else) which I don't like.

To achieve rendering Child.cshtml within Parent.cshtml and still handle Post methods, etc., in Child's pageModel, you can try to use javascript. If unnecessary, I still recommend using partial views which are simpler than other methods.
